# Horizontal webpage in WebKit

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, css

I'm trying to create a webpage that is simular to "[The Horizontal Way](http://www.thehorizontalway.com/)." The goal is to make all the container boxes fall horizontally instead of vertically without setting the width of the body.

Bellow is a basic version of my page. I've also played around with the idea of rotating the body 90deg but quickly ran into limitations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 4000px;
            }
            .box {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 99%;
                width: 300px;
                margin: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: #FBF;
                -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
            }
            .box:hover {
                width: 600px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">One</div>
        <div class="box">Two</div>
        <div class="box">Three</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not concerned with compatibility in other browsers but it must work in rescent versions of WebKit (Safari 5, Chrome 9, etc.).

**edit:** While looking at the base [stylesheet for webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) I had come across the '-webkit-block-flow' property. I wasn't able to find much information on this, but it might give me the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: It's helpful if you state the problem you have with your current code.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the above effect **without** setting a body width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the -webkit-box display type I was able to achieve exactly what I was looking for. I've posted the revised code bellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            .box {
                width: 300px;
                margin: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: #FBF;
                -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
            }
            .box:hover {
                width: 600px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">One</div>
        <div class="box">Two</div>
        <div class="box">Three</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the most simple solution would be an unordered list with list elements containing body text/content.

Comment: That doesn't change the overflow behavior that I'm looking for.